# How to replace if with a loop?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

this is my message :

```
03-08-2020 06:00:01  /soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/lance_autofd10.sos ---> /soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/wfc_automate_genere_G_WFL10.sos wfc1 wfc100 wfc2 wfc200 10 CLOCTRL 1
MESSAGE AUTOMATE 03/08/2020 06:00:01 : DEMARRAGE TRAITEMENT JOURNEE DU 20200731

(1 row affected)
/soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/wfc_automate_genere_G_WFL10.sos => MESSAGE AUTOMATE 03/08/2020 06:00:01 : POUR LA JOURNEE DU 20200731 L'ETAPE UNIP A PRIS 00H00
/soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/wfc_automate_genere_G_WFL10.sos => MESSAGE AUTOMATE (CYCLE G) 03/08/2020 06:00:01 : 
FIN DU TRAITEMENT UNIP () JOURNEE DU 20200731
(1 row affected)
     
 --- 
   1 

(1 row affected)
(1 row affected)
----------- Fichiers de traces
/soft/rilprdaglm/logs/appel_rmi_lancements_22646.log
/soft/ldsrmi/G_ILPRDAGLM_1/log/Loader_G_ILPRDAGLM_1_Report_E0_S472_Gwfc_ctr_unicrs_482.log
Lancer quand la tâche sera terminée
grep -h PROCESSUS /soft/ldsrmi/G_ILPRDAGLM_1/log/Loader_G_ILPRDAGLM_1_Report_E0_S472_Gwfc_ctr_unicrs_482.log
(1 row affected)
     
 --- 
   0 

(1 row affected)
(1 row affected)
/soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/wfc_automate_genere_G_WFL10.sos => MESSAGE AUTOMATE 03/08/2020 06:14:01 : POUR LA JOURNEE DU 20200731 L'ETAPE UNIC A PRIS 00H14
/soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/wfc_automate_genere_G_WFL10.sos => MESSAGE AUTOMATE (CYCLE G) 03/08/2020 06:14:01 : 
FIN DU TRAITEMENT UNIC () JOURNEE DU 20200731

     
 --- 
   0 

(1 row affected)
(1 row affected)
/soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/wfc_automate_genere_G_WFL10.sos => MESSAGE AUTOMATE 03/08/2020 06:14:01 : POUR LA JOURNEE DU 20200731 L'ETAPE CHGFI1 A PRIS 00H00
/soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/wfc_automate_genere_G_WFL10.sos => MESSAGE AUTOMATE (CYCLE G) 03/08/2020 06:14:01 : 
FIN DU TRAITEMENT CHGFI1 () JOURNEE DU 20200731


(1 row affected)
(1 row affected)
/soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/wfc_automate_genere_G_WFL10.sos => MESSAGE AUTOMATE 03/08/2020 06:14:01 : POUR LA JOURNEE DU 20200731 L'ETAPE RCOU A PRIS 00H00
/soft/rilprdaglm/scripts/wfc_automate_genere_G_WFL10.sos => MESSAGE AUTOMATE (CYCLE G) 03/08/2020 06:14:01 : 
FIN DU TRAITEMENT RCOU () JOURNEE DU 20200731
(1 row affected)
```

and this my logstash.conf

```
 if [message] =~ "ETAPE"
  
  {
  
  grok {  
     match => { "message" => "%{URIPATHPARAM:source} %{NOTSPACE:msg} %{WORD:msg} %{WORD:type} %{DATE_EU:date} %{TIME:heure} %{NOTSPACE:msg} %{WORD:msg} %{WORD:msg} %{WORD:msg} %{WORD:msg} %{WORD:msg} (?<etape>\S+[[:punct:]][A-Z]{5}) %{WORD:nom_tache} %{WORD:msg} %{WORD:msg} %{WORD:temps_execution}"}
      }
  }
```

i want to replace the if by a loop so that every time when it finds the word "ETAPE" executes the grok filter.In kibana it shows only the first "ETAPE".Need help.Due to my research i can't use for or while

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure from the information provided, but it looks to me like you have a single "message" field there.

If so, you might find the [`split` filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html) useful for splitting the message into separate lines. Then your existing conditional and grok config should `Just Work`.

Logstash has no concept of the 'loop'. It just runs through the pipeline once per event. If you want multiple things to happen, you need to get the data into multiple events.

There are also other filter plugins - as well as input codecs - that will create more events, if `split` doesn't meet your needs.